# Adding PNG watermark in PNG image PHP

Tags: php

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1kVz.png

I'm trying to copy PNG to another PNG but I have no idea why they return like this

```
    <?php // File and new size
$filename = 'watermark.png';

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

// Load

$resim = 'http://www.petrominpng.com.pg/images/logo_big.png';

$ext = end(explode('.', $resim));


if($ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "jpg")
{
$thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($resim); 
}
else if($ext == "png")
{
$thumb = imagecreatefrompng($resim); 
}

$sx = imagesx($thumb);
$sy = imagesy($thumb);

if($sx >= $sy)
{
    $sxd = $sx/2;
    $degisim = $sxd/$width;
    /*
    echo $sxd." ".$width."  ";
    echo $sxd-$width." |";
    */
    $sxy = $height * $degisim;
    /*
    echo " $sxy $height | $degisim";
    exit();
    */
}
else
{
    $sxy = $sy/2;
    $degisim = $sxy/$height;
    /*
    echo $sxd." ".$width."  ";
    echo $sxd-$width." |";
    */
    $sxd = $width * $degisim;
    /*
    echo " $sxy $height | $degisim";
    exit();
    */
}

$source = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, $sx/5, $sy/4, 0, 0, $sxd, $sxy, $width, $height);

// Output
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);


?>
```

You can see that, i have problem with images how can i make it right ?

my watermark

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFCa.png

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, it appears that something is wrong with the base PNG image (not the watermark) because if you try the code with another png, it works fine, with a jpg, it also works fine.

It seems to be because the original PNG is a PNG8, because when converted to a PNG32 it works fine.

Comment: How can i convert it to PNG32

Comment: FYI... in photoshop, even when you say to create a 32bit PNG, it still generates an 8 bit PNG

Comment: It's possible with imagick

$im = new Imagick($image);
$im->setImageDepth(32);
$im->setImageFormat('PNG32');
$im->writeImage($filename);

Comment: Oh, when I try to make it 32bit I cant select transparent background, and I want to convert it on my own not with PHP

Comment: Here is a PNG32 version of your image : http://s22.postimg.org/vgouhyhb5/image.png

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. It works fine in my project.

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng('source.png');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 1;
$marge_bottom = 1;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// OUTPUT IMAGE:
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagepng($im, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The watermark image should be in one of the following recommended
>   formats:
>
> - PNG-8 (recommended)
> - Colors: 256 or less
> - Transparency: On/Off
> - GIF
> - Colors: 256 or less
> - Transparency: On/Off
> - JPEG
> - Colors: True color
> - Transparency: n/a
>
> The imagecopymerge function does not properly handle the PNG-24
>   images; it is therefore not recommended.
>
> If you are using Adobe Photoshop to create watermark images, it is
>   recommended that you use "Save for Web" command with the following
>   settings:
>
> File Format: PNG-8, non-interlaced
>
> Color Reduction: Selective, 256 colors
>
> Dithering: Diffusion, 88%
>
> Transparency: On, Matte: None
>
> Transparency Dither: Diffusion Transparency Dither, 100%

Comment: When i just did like what you said, http://u1312.hizliresim.com/1j/8/vb7hn.png It's like that now